# Identify tail light

Tags: part-identification, tail-lights

My wife found this in our driveway this afternoon and to me it looks like a tailight lens to a car but I'm really no car expert so could someone please identify this for us and the make and model if possible so we can get it back to the owners so they don't have to buy a new one

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It looks like some kind of marker ... could be tail light, but I'd bet it would come from the front end. It's clear and yellow. Most tail light lenses are red. I would have no idea what it came off of though.

Comment: Of some help could be the yellow part. Most modern cars have clear indicator lens, because the bulb is yellow. However, old cars use a yellow indicator lens. I would bet the car is at least 15 years old.

Answer (score 2):

This is a tail light from a 2001 F-150.  (Good detective work, @juhist!)

Look similar?

[image: F-150 tail light]

Obviously, yours is a left light, whereas this one is a right light.

---

Now for the confession.  I didn't just happen to know off the top of my head that that was what the F-150 taillights look like.  But if you look in the top right hand corner of your picture, you'll see the Ford symbol a bit vaguely.  A bit of photo editing also brought the model number on the light out of the top right corner of the clear section.  It's SAE AIP 2 P 96 TK.

Comment: NOICE! Great job! :o) +1 for sure.

Comment: Haha, just happened to see that one.  :)